# undefined when retrieving e.target.File when uploading file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to obtain the `File` value within this stack trace

[image]

however im getting an undefined when calling it like

`console.log(e.target.File);`

or

`console.log(e.target)`

How would i access the file value ?

```
handleUpload = (e) => {
    const data = new FormData()
    console.log(e.target);

    // data.append('file', e.target.files[0])
    // data.append('name', 'some value user types')
    // data.append('description', 'some value user types')
    // Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
    // console.log(response);
    debugger;
    //   this.setState({
    //     imageUrl: response.data.fileUrl
    //   })

render(){
    return(
       .......           
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                withPreview={true}
                buttonText='Upload an image'
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                onChange={this.handleUpload}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
                />
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are hooking up/calling your `handleUpload`? In the screenshot your provide `e` is an array of files already, but in your code you are attempting to access `e` as though it is an interaction event.

Comment: Please provide the code used to attach/bind the handleUpload function to en event.

Comment: ok will do in one sec. i found a temp solution e[0] will update the code.

Comment: If `console.log(e.target)` prints `undefined` then `console.log(e.target.File);` will throw an error. And from your screenshot `e` is an array of files, hence... `e[0]` would be the file.

Comment: e[0] gives the value im looking for, but its sorta "hacky" it doesn't seem like a proper way to retrieve a file. I updated the code.

Comment: What's "hacky" about accessing the first element in an array? o.O

Comment: well i guess e[0] will do. i was thinking of something more along the lines like `e.target.files.value[0]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the implementation of `ImageUploader` but from the screenshot it seems that it calls the `onChange` method with an array of files. So you can access them like that:

```
handleImagesChange = images => {
  const firstImage = images[0];
  console.log(firstImage.name);
  this.setState({ images });
}

handleSubmit = () => {
  Axios.post('some/url', this.state.images)
    .then(console.log)
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. I assumed you would have a separate button that would call `handleSubmit` but you can also `Axios.post` the images every time they change, if you want...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using a React `ImageUploader` component that is already handling extracting your files from the event. The `e` in your `handleUpload` isn't an event rather than the extracted file list. You should work with this file list directly.

You can look into the `ImageUploader` source to see how it is handling it if you would like to better understand, but accessing the files through `e[0]` is fine (you may want to rename `e` to something like `files` for clarity though).

Comment: oh ok willl try that out, for clarity purpose.